thread.join() blocks an async function
I am developing a telegram bot using python-telegram-bot. It is like a stock screener, it analyzes the market every given interval and sends the results to users that are subscribed to the indicator. The problem is I do not want the bot to be blocked (users continuously interact with it) when it is analyzing the market (it fetches data & has a lot of computations). So I thought I needed to do that in a different thread, but I can't make it work with the asyncio
Here is the example:
async def run_screener(bot):
    while True:
    
        async def heavy_computations():
            for i in range(5):
                await asyncio.sleep(2)
                print("Doing computations")

        compute = threading.Thread(target=lambda: asyncio.run(heavy_computations()))
        compute.start()
        compute.join()  #   <--- This is blocking the bot
        
        # Computations are done, now send the results with the bot
        for user_id in users:
            await bot.send_message(text=results, chat_id=user_id)

        await asyncio.sleep(compute_next_time())
        

async def main():
    application = buildBot()
    
    async with application:
        await application.start()
        await application.updater.start_polling()
        
        await run_screener(application.bot)
        
        await application.updater.stop()
        await application.stop()

asyncio.run(main())


Do the answers to this question help at all?

I don't know if it is good idea to mix async and threads. I'm not sure but asyncio already uses threads to run tasks. OR maybe you should run your code between start() and join(), not after join()

@furas There is no problem with combining threads and asyncio.  There are functions in asyncio that are explicitly designed to support that.  And asyncio does NOT use threads to run tasks - an asyncio event loop is dedicated to a single thread.

To run a non-asyncio task and await its completion without blocking other asyncio tasks tou use method asyncio.loop.run_in_executor. You can either execute your non-asyncio worker function in a multiprocessing pool or a multithreading pool. Since you are using multithreading we can either run the task in a default multithreading pool provided by the asyncio loop or create a custom pool, as we are doing here (in this case we only need a pool size of 1):
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import time

async def task1():
    # Emulate doing some processing:
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return 1

async def task2():
    # Use a ProcessPoolExecutor if the processing is CPU-intensive:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(1) as executor:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, io_task)
    return result

def io_task():
    # Emulate doing some processing:
    time.sleep(2)
    return 2

async def main():
    results = await asyncio.gather(task1(), task2())
    print(results)

asyncio.run(main())

Prints:
[1, 2]


I don't think there's a need for explicitly getting a ThreadPoolExecutor(1), getting the loop, and calling loop.run_in_executor. Instead, just use asyncio.to_thread.

@bmitc Yes, that is another way which just ultimately calls loop.run_in_executor with None as the executor argument. This results in creating a default thread pool by calling executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(thread_name_prefix='asyncio') . You will be creating a pool of size min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4), which will be at least 32 threads and way more than what is needed for this example. So I wanted to show how to create a custom pool with the size that is actually needed. I also mentioned in my answer that one could use the default pool instead.

t = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(...))
t.start()
t.join()  #   <--- This is ALWAYS a mistake.

There is never any reason  reason to start a thread and then immediately join it. You are complaining that compute.join() "blocks" the caller, but blocking the caller is the only thing that join() is ever supposed to do.
compute.join() does nothing to the compute thread. It does nothing at all to any thread or, to anything else. compute.join() does nothing until the compute thread has finished, and then it returns. That's it. That's all it does.
I don't know anything about telegram. I don't know what you actually are trying to do, but it sounds like you'll need to re-structure your code so that run_screener does not wait until "Computations are done." Instead, you'll either need to make the new thread itself "send the results with the bot," or else you'll need to make the new thread trigger some event that will cause some other thread to "send the results with the bot."

P.S., The reason why threads exist is, so you can do this:
t = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(...))
t.start()
doSomethingElse_concurrently_withFoo()

And, the reason why join exists is, that foo might produce a result that you want to use later:
t = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(...))
t.start()
doSomethingElse_concurrently_withFoo()
t.join()
doSomethingWithResultFromFoo()

